# make xterm window open until it's closed by user

Tags: python, linux, pyqt

how to call a permanent xterm window and it's closed only when user close it?

here's the code that will recreate this problem

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from main import Ui_MainWindow

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.pushID, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.showid)

    def showid(self):
        process = subprocess.Popen(['lsusb'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        process.communicate()[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Note that 'xterm XYZ' will cause xterm to execute XYZ as a shell. That is, xterm is expecting something like /bin/sh and not any other type of executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `os.system`. Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['xterm'])
```

Though you are better getting the output from `subprocess` without involving `xterm`.

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['lsusb'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> process.communicate()[0]
```

Note that `shell=False`. This is how you would read the output from the `lsusb` command.

If you are looking for a tutorial on `subprocess`, [this](http://blog.doughellmann.com/2007/07/pymotw-subprocess.html) is good.

Comment: umm.. how can this work with PyQt4?? i want to make the shell appear with lsusb output inside it when some button is clicked.. i just want the code to make the shell appear with lsusb output inside it..

Comment: I can't give you the code, but you can read it up for a better understanding. What you are asking for is pretty is. http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS47.html

Comment: Basically, read any PyQt tutorial and you will figure this out easily.

Comment: output = process.communicate()[0]. Print `output` and then seen.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but what the OP wanted in this case was:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['xterm','-hold','-title','Usb Devices Available','-geometry','80x30+2000+0','-e','lsusb'])
```

-hold (keep the xterm window open once it has executed)
-title (the name in the xterm window) without -title the window takes the name of the command executed, in this case `lsusb`
-geometry (terminal width, height,horizontal position, vertical position)
-e (everything after this is the command to run)
lsusb (the command I wish to run in xterm)